# How to handle menu bar in Cypress

Tags: cypress

I am trying to click the search bar either on the sidebar `<im-sidebar class="hydrated">` or top menu `<nav_class = "top-menu">`.
This is the code

[image]

So I tried: `cy.get('.moduleSearchbar').click()`
But Cypress does not find it.

I also used the Cypress recorder, but using this plugin, it records the same code  `cy.get('.dx-viewport > app-root > .ng-star-inserted > .hydrated').click()` several times, regardless of where I click.
It seems the sidebar and top menu are hiding the buttons and Cypress just see the same element all over the page.
I really appreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take note that the `.moduleSearchbar` element is inside a `shadow-root`. This means that these elements are part of a "Shadow DOM" (see [the W3C note about Shadow DOM](https://www.w3.org/TR/shadow-dom/) and the top answer in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34119639/what-is-shadow-root) for more about this).

According to the Cypress documentation, you cannot "just" click (or generally interact with) an element in a shadow DOM. You'll need to use the [.shadow() command](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/shadow.html) to get "inside" the shadow DOM.
In your case, you would probably need to write something like this:

```
cy
.get('im-sidebar')
.shadow()
.find('.moduleSearchbar')
.click()
```

Comment: tks for your tip. I used    ```cy.get('im-root.hydrated').shadow().find('div #container').click() ```. Now at least cypress is finding the  Shadow Dom, but it can not finding yet any element inside it.

Comment: @IngriddBrito most of the stuff inside the `im-root`, and notably the searchbar, also are in their own shadow DOMs. You'll probably need to chain multiple `.shadow()` calls at some point. A good way to check if `.shadow()` works as expected is to see if it can find the `div#root`, `div#main`, or the `im-sidebar` that are immediately in the first shadow DOM.

Comment: My previous comment was almost correct. Before, it was .find('div #container'). Cypress didn't find it because there was a space before #. I fixed it to ('div#container'), and it is working now. Tks!